# How to show that the $f$ is one-one and onto?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $x$ and $y$ be distinct elements of order $2$ in $G$ that generate $G$. Prove that $G \cong D_{2n}$, where $n = |xy|.$

**My attempt** : Since every element  of $G$ can be written as  $x^a (xy)^b$ for $ 0 \le a\le 2$ and $0 \le b \le n$

let  define a function  $f : D_{2n} \to G $ by $$f(s^ar^b)=x^a(xy)^b$$

Now we can easily showed that  $f$ is homomorphism

My question  : How to show that the $f$ is one-one and onto ?

My attempt : to show $f$ is one-one ,we must have

$$f(s^ar^b)=f(s^cr^d)$$

$$x^a(xy)^b=x^c(xy)^d$$

to show $f$ is onto ,we have $$f(s^ar^b)=x^a(xy)^b$$

Comment: Is your definition of $D_{2n}=\langle\,x,y\mid x^2=y^2=(xy)^n=1\,\rangle$? Then you readily get an epimorphism $D_{2n}\to G$, for example.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes..but  i don't know  about epimorphism .Is there  any other way to show $f$ is one-one and onto ?

Comment: First prove that if $G$ is **any** group with generating set $A$ and $H$ is **any** group with a generating set $B$ and $f: G\to H$ is a homomorphism such that $f(A)=B$, then $f$ onto.

Comment: As for injectivity, my suggestion is to prove that the order of both groups in your question is $2n$. Then, can you prove that a surjective map between two finite sets of the same cardinality is also injective?

Comment: @MoisheKohan yes by mapping $s \to x$ and $r \to (xy)$

Comment: @jasmine Good, now follow my suggestion about general groups.